# How to update a django model value from a button click in a class view

Tags: python, django

I currently have a model that looks like:

**Model**

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_best_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def set_best_answer(self):
        self.is_best_answer = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('question-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.question.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Answer by {self.author} with text: {self.content}"
```

I have a Class based `Listview` which lists all of the answers above. I want to add a button in the template that would update the value in the model of `is_best_answer` to `True` e.g.

**html**

`<a class="btn btn-outline-dark " href="{% url 'select' answer.id %}">Set Best Answer</a>`

**view**

```
def set_best_(request, pk):
    answer = Answer.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
    answer.set_best_answer()

    return redirect('/')
```

**url**

```
path('answer/<int:pk>/best-answer/',  set_best, name='select'),
```

The above works for me, but I have had to call a function rather than anything to do with the class based views. Is there a better way?

Dango version 3.1

Comment: Im of the view that a serializer should always be used and you should simply expose an api from the backend. Try out django rest framework it will save you the headache of such tasks. you simply post a dictionary of values and their respectively updated fields. then let the serializer check if the values are ok and the relevant model will be updated. the post contains a dictionary of any subset of the fields in the model.

Comment: otherwise your method is fine, but this will become cumbersome when things get more complex.

Comment: I believe this approach is acceptable since ListView is purposely made to render the objects of a model and setting the best answer is a custom task that doesn't relate to ListView.

Comment: @OctaviodelSer - thanks, do you have a link to documentation for an example of this using django rest? I will start to look into learning the framework in the mean time.

Comment: @spotnag Django rest framework has a whole website dedicated to tutorials. I recommend getting a sample blank project (they probably have one) which works and go from there .